# Методы с переменным числом параметров

Tags: java, функции

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые программисты. На первом курсе ВУЗа краем глаза учили С++ и оттуда я узнал, что в этом языке есть функции с неопределенным количеством параметров, вроде бы через троеточие это делалось. Сам я учу Java и мне стало интересно, существует ли такая вещь здесь. Поиски в гугле особо ничего не дали. Нашел только вариант, где в параметры передается массив объектов. Но примерчик был 2005 года. Так что всё же решил поинтересоваться здесь. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Видимо вы имели ввиду "[Методы с переменным числом параметров Java](http://crypto.pp.ua/2010/06/metody-s-peremennym-chislom-parametrov-java/)"